# AWS API Gateway to Lambda to DynamoDB restrict data by API key

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-api-gateway

I am looking to create a REST API gateway which connects to my DynamoDB database but only outputs data for the user specific to the API Key that is connected.

I can't seem to find any information on how to restrict the DynamoDB calls based on the API/user connected.

I would assume I need to create another table/section that manages which data (IDs) are allowed to be viewed per API key.

So essentially what I want is:

User sends a GET to the REST API to retrieve all the entries from the DynamoDB database related to their devices ID.

DEVICE ID: 44DDTTRR

This then outputs the data only for that device ID.

---

The issue is that I am not sure where is the best place to check if that API user has access to that device ID, as I don't want people to just access all the devices, just the ones that are attached to their API key.

API Gateway

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Cognito User Pools, you can use the context object in VTL to construct your DynamoDB query. If you set the partition key to the user's email or sub claim from Cognito and the sort key to the device ID, then if a user submits a device ID which they do not own, the DynamoDB query result will return with zero results.

If you are not using Cognito, you can achieve the same effect using an API Gateway authoriser Lambda.